# Is it possible to use an \hdashrule inside a \ctable as a \midrule?

Tags: tables, line-spacing, ctable

I would like to know if there is a way to use an `\hdashrule` or `\hdashline` inside a `\ctable`as a `\midrule`? If possible, it will obey to the same *rules* as the `\midrule` command, like adjusting automatically to the **table width** and conserving the **vertical spacing** between the rows.

I tried the following table :

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage{multicol,bm}
\usepackage{array, booktabs}
\usepackage{ctable, dashrule}
\usepackage[left=2cm, right=2cm, top=2cm, bottom=2cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\ctable[caption= {Paramètres},
        label  = {tab:paramètres},
        ]
        {m{6.cm} m{3.5cm} l }
        {\tnote[$\ast$]{Dans le repère du solide.} \tnote[$\ast \ast$]{Autour de l'axe de rotation.}}{
        \toprule
            &   \textbf{Premier Solide} &   \textbf{Deuxième Solide}\\
        \midrule
        \textbf{Masse (kg)} &   4,4839  &   3,8177\\
        \multicolumn{3}{c}{\hdashrule{8cm}{1pt}{1pt 5pt}} \\
        \textbf{Centre de masse\tmark[$\ast$] ($\bm{x}\,;\, \bm{y}$) (m)}   &   (0 ; 0,1940)    & (0 ; 0,1613)\\
        \multicolumn{3}{c}{\hdashrule{8cm}{1pt}{1pt 5pt}} \\
        \textbf{Moment d'inertie\tmark[$\ast \ast$] (kg$\cdot$m\textsuperscript 2)}&    0,0913  &   0,0615\\
        \bottomrule}

\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, these dashed lines don't adjust automatically to the table width, and even worse, they do not conserve the vertical spacing between rows!

Is there a way to make this simple and automatic?

Note : I also tried replacing

```
\multicolumn{3}{c}{\hdashrule{8cm}{1pt}{1pt 5pt}}
```

by

```
\hdashline[1pt/3pt]
```

`\hdashline` has the advantage to automatically adjust to the table width, but it doesn't conserve the `booktabs` vertical spacing laws. Also, one can't control the size of the dashed line using this command.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

new version keeping the rule within the table

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage{multicol,bm}
\usepackage{array, booktabs}
\usepackage{ctable, dashrule}

 \usepackage[left=2cm, right=2cm, top=2cm, bottom=2cm]{geometry}

\makeatletter

\def\xmidrule{%
\noalign{\vskip\aboverulesep}%
\multispan{3}{\leaders\hbox to 4pt{\hss\vrule\@height\cmidrulewidth\@width 2pt \relax\hss}\hfill\kern0pt}\cr%
\noalign{\vskip\belowrulesep}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}


\noindent X \dotfill X

\ctable[caption= {Paramètres},
        label  = {tab:paramètres},
        ]
        {m{6.cm} m{3.5cm} l }
        {\tnote[$\ast$]{Dans le repère du solide.} \tnote[$\ast \ast$]{Autour de l'axe de rotation.}}{
        \toprule
            &   \textbf{Premier Solide} &   \textbf{Deuxième Solide}\\
        \midrule
        \textbf{Masse (kg)} &   4,4839  &   3,8177\\
        \xmidrule
        \textbf{Centre de masse\tmark[$\ast$] ($\bm{x}\,;\, \bm{y}$) (m)}   &   (0 ; 0,1940)    & (0 ; 0,1613)\\
        \multicolumn{3}{c}{\hdashrule{8cm}{1pt}{1pt 5pt}} \\
        \textbf{Moment d'inertie\tmark[$\ast \ast$] (kg$\cdot$m\textsuperscript 2)}&    0,0913  &   0,0615\\
        \bottomrule}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! The issue is that I tried your solution, and it extends to the full length of the document. What I mean is that when you modify the geometry and add the following line to the header : `\usepackage[left=2cm, right=2cm, top=2cm, bottom=2cm]{geometry}`, the line gets out of the table...

Comment: @jrojasqu code updated

Comment: I don't mean to be annoying... But how do you define the `\xmidrule`? I can't find it in your answer...

Comment: oops:-)........ it was there in my file, obviously cut and paste is beyond my skills....

Comment: try now, sorry about that:-)

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is **exactly** what I was looking for! Now I know how they put these tables on the cereal boxes... (just kidding! :-) Thanks again!